# Typescript: как создать функцию, принимающую аргумент типа Object и возвращающую некий другой интерфейс

Tags: typescript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например так:

```
createSort(v = {
a: 2, b: 3, c: 4
}) // return { order: Order, orderBy: keyof v, sortableFn... }
```

Comment: вы сейчас возвращаете тип, а не значение. Посмотрите, какую ошибку выдает компилятор?

Comment: надо типо `return {order, sortableFn}`

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы функция принимала объект с полями данных, а возвращала интерфейс/абстрактный класс, такое возможно сделать? Заранее спасибо!
func f(data = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }): interface SortableElementI { order, orderBy = keyof data, sortableFN }

Comment: То есть я хочу вернуть тип (вернее интерфейс)

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно вернуть какие-то определенные данные в нужном формате, то можно использовать кастинг

```
interface Data {
  str: string;
  num: number;
}

const getDataFromRequest = (request: any): Data => {
  return <Data>{
    str: '',
    num: 0,
  }
}
```